# Drawing text failes with 1282 error | GLFW3 & Freetype

Tags: opengl, glsl, glfw, freetype

I'm currently building my own game in c++ using OpenGL. I wanted to try something new because I mainly code in C# and Unity. My goal is to first find out how everything works before I begin making my game. So I tried Rendering strings or text to the Screen but failed. I tried many things from working with stb_truetype and shader to firetype. My current try is with freetype because I got suggest to do so.

But after multiple tries I still wasn't able to print a "Hello World" to the screen. I added debugging stuff and tried arround and found out that the problem lays inside the "RenderText" function.

Output of the "Debugger"/the logging:

```
Shader compiled successfully
Shader compiled successfully
Program linked successfully
after glBufferSubData glError (0x502)
after glDrawArrays glError (0x502)
```

I tried playing arround with variables and librarys and diffrent shader code but didn't got it working. (All paths are correct)

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

void checkGlError(const char* op) {
    for (GLint error = glGetError(); error; error = glGetError()) {
        std::cout << "after " << op << " glError (0x" << std::hex << error << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

struct Character {
    GLuint     TextureID;  // ID handle of the glyph texture
    glm::ivec2 Size;       // Size of glyph
    glm::ivec2 Bearing;    // Offset from baseline to left/top of glyph
    GLuint     Advance;    // Offset to advance to next glyph
};


std::map<GLchar, Character> Characters;
GLuint VAO, VBO;


GLuint compileShader(const GLchar *shaderCode, GLenum shaderType) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    if(success) {
        std::cout << "Shader compiled successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    return shader;
}

GLuint linkProgram(GLuint vertexShader, GLuint fragmentShader) {
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint success;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    if (success) {
        std::cout << "Program linked successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return program;
}


void RenderText(GLuint shader, std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, glm::vec3 color) {
    // Activate corresponding render state
    glUseProgram(shader);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "textColor"), color.x, color.y, color.z);
    checkGlError("glUniform3f");
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    checkGlError("glActiveTexture");
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    checkGlError("glBindVertexArray");


    // Iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
        Character ch = Characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
                { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
                { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },

                { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 }
        };
        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        checkGlError("glBindTexture");
        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        checkGlError("glBufferSubData");
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale;
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

std::string readShaderFromFile(const std::string& filepath) {
    std::ifstream shaderFile(filepath);
    std::stringstream shaderData;
    shaderData << shaderFile.rdbuf();
    shaderFile.close();
    return shaderData.str();
}


int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        // Initialization failed
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        // Window or OpenGL context creation failed
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// GLEW initialization
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        std::cout << "Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "../Arial.ttf", 0, &face)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load font" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

    if (FT_Load_Char(face, 'X', FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Compile shaders and link them into a program
    std::string vertexShaderSrc = readShaderFromFile("../shader.vs");
    std::string fragmentShaderSrc = readShaderFromFile("../shader.fs");

    GLuint vertexShader = compileShader(vertexShaderSrc.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = compileShader(fragmentShaderSrc.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint shaderProgram = linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;

        RenderText(shaderProgram, "Hello World!", 25.0f, 25.0f, 1.0f, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.8f, 0.2f));

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You are never creating a buffer. You need to create VBO before using it by calling the `glGenBuffers` method.

Comment: Thanks I don't get errors anymore but the string is still not visible

Comment: I found the problem. I forgot to set the projection matrix